# When I lose my domain records in route53 if i stop paying for route53/amazon account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

As you understand from title i have trouble with payments
route53 contain few domain and many sub-domains
Can somebody say when amazon destroy my account and all my domains and sub-domains?

UDP: i didn't pay almost 2 month. I don't wont to close my account. I'm wait when i get enough money to pay my bill. And another question: in all cases amazon will close account in the next month ?

Comment: This is something you should open an AWS support ticket for.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no one here can authoritatively tell you how long AWS might allow your services to linger on an unpaid account without loss of data.  Any experiences would be anectotal.  Your default assumption with *any* service provider is that unless other arrangements have been negotiated, services you are not paying for are subject to permanent deletion at any time. tl;dr: Contact AWS Billing & Account Support.

Comment: Not a problem. Just close.

Answer (score 1):

About Route 53 pricing,
With Hosted-zone, check [This Link](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/pricing/). You must pay with monthly billing 
And with Domain, you already paid when you buy them. Pricing: [This link](https://d32ze2gidvkk54.cloudfront.net/Amazon_Route_53_Domain_Registration_Pricing_20140731.pdf)

About aws account, your account will be closed in the next month with condition:

1. You already paid all your billing until the end of month
2. Go to Aws Account page and click "Close Account". [Ref](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/close-account.html)

Comment: i didn't pay almost 2 month. I don't wont to close my account. I'm wait when i get enough money to pay my bill. And another question: in all cases amazon will close account in the next month ?

Comment: no, aws only closes your account when you want. If not, you just need to pay all your billing. That's all